# Nullable CC and BCC in sending emails through SSIS

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am working on a code wherein it sends emails to recipients using script task in SSIS 2008r2. It works fine when all address boxes are populated (To, Cc, and Bcc), however I'm getting error when one of these boxes are blank/null. I'd like to have that option to have these boxes null. Here's the code I'm working on:

```vb
Public Sub SendMailMessage( _
    ByVal From As String, ByVal SendTo As String, _
    ByVal SendCc As String, ByVal SendBcc As String, _
    ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Body As String, _
    ByVal Attachment As String, ByVal IsBodyHtml As Boolean, ByVal Server As String)

    Dim htmlMessage As MailMessage
    Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient
    Dim myAttachment As Attachment
    Dim myBcc As MailAddress = New MailAddress(SendBcc)
    Dim myCc As MailAddress = New MailAddress(SendCc)


    htmlMessage = New MailMessage( _
      From, SendTo, Subject, Body)

    myAttachment = New Attachment(Attachment)
    htmlMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml
    htmlMessage.Attachments.Add(myAttachment)
    htmlMessage.CC.Add(myCc)
    htmlMessage.Bcc.Add(myBcc)

    mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient(Server)
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    mySmtpClient.Send(htmlMessage)
End Sub

Public Sub Main()

    Dim htmlMessageTo As String = _
    Replace(Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailTo").Value.ToString, ";", ",")
    Dim htmlMessageCC As String = _
    Replace(Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailCc").Value.ToString, ";", ",")
    Dim htmlMessageBCC As String = _
    Replace(Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailBcc").Value.ToString, ";", ",")
    Dim htmlMessageFrom As String = _
      Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailFrom").Value.ToString
    Dim htmlMessageSubject As String = _
      Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailSubject").Value.ToString
    Dim htmlMessageBody As String = _
      Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailBody").Value.ToString
    Dim MailBody As String = File.ReadAllText(htmlMessageBody)
    Dim htmlAttachments As String = _
      Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailAttachment").Value.ToString
    Dim smtpServer As String = _
      Dts.Variables("HtmlEmailServer").Value.ToString


    SendMailMessage( _
        htmlMessageFrom, htmlMessageTo, htmlMessageCC, _
        htmlMessageBCC, htmlMessageSubject, MailBody, htmlAttachments, _
        True, smtpServer)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact text of the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple: don't add CC or BCC if they are empty - look at the documentation for [MailAddressCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx) - it clearly states that ArgumentNullException or ArgumentException is raised if the values are empty or NULL

```vb
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myCC) Then
   htmlMessage.CC.Add(myCc)
End If

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myBcc)) Then
   htmlMessage.Bcc.Add(myBcc)
End If
```

Note: VB Syntax could be wrong but that's the idea.

Comment: Apart from that `string` should be `String` in VB.NET the syntax is correct. Nice answer!